# Bottomless stack of NullPointerExceptions

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception

I'm using the debugger in Eclipse to help me with a Java project. I'm seeing a NullPointerException whose "cause" field/attribute (not sure what the correct term is) points to another NullPointerException, whose cause points to another one and so and so forth. I've followed the stack down through about 100 of these without reaching the bottom.

I'm not necessarily asking for help fixing the error but why does this seemingly bottomless stack occur?

For all of them it says their value is "NullPointerException (id 38)". Is there just one instance that is referring to itself?

Cheers!

Comment: I'd be willing to bet it isn't bottomless.

Comment: It's hard to tell you without seeing any of the code.

Comment: ... or the stacktrace.

Comment: You can set a breakpoint on `NullPointerException`: in the Breakpoints view click the `J!` icon.  This should stop at the initial NPE if you check both Suspend checkboxes.

Comment: _"Is there just one instance that is referring to itself?"_  Yes, that is what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that the value is always ending in (id 38) tells you that yes, it is referring to itself. The number in parentheses denotes the object instance. So the NullPointerException points to itself.

I have already seen this a few times. Sometimes an exception just mentions itself as a cause. I haven't ever really investigated in why this happens though.

Comment: Well OK then. Thank you (and everyone) for your suggestions. I still don't know why it's self referencing but I've found the source of the problem so it doesn't matter now

Answer (score 0):

You could try to `catch` the exception, then run it through

```
  public static Throwable getRootCause(Throwable throwable) {
    Throwable cause;
    while ((cause = throwable.getCause()) != null) {
      throwable = cause;
    }
    return throwable;
  }
```

and see if there is a bottom. `getRootCause(evilNPE).printStackTrace()`.

(code stolen from [Guava `Throwables#getRootCause()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Throwables.html#getRootCause%28java.lang.Throwable%29))

Exceptions should always have a root cause, it should be technically possible to create an infinite loop but I think you would need reflection or other very non-standard use of exceptions to achieve that. If that's really the case you would loop forever in above method.

You are probably dealing with recursion in a way like

```
void recursion(int steps) {
    try {
        if (steps > 0)
            recursion(steps - 1);
        else
            throw new Exception("Hidden root");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Wrap Exception because we can", e);
    }
}
```

where each exception is caught, wrapped and propagated to the next outer step.

It is on the other hand possible that you misinterpret something, e.g. you follow a reference to `this`, which has a reference to `this` again.